# Safari browser : Selenium Webdriver exceptions

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I'm running Selenium tests on safari 6. When use javascript executor to find viewport height

```
public static String scrollHeightCommand = return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
initialHeight = ((Long) (jsx.executeScript(scrollHeightCommand)))
```

I'm getting this exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.each(function(value, index) {
  results.push(iterator(value, index));
})') (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

But, when I run the javscript command on the console in Safari manually, it returns the value of the viewport. Can anyone point out the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the selenium webdriver extension in safari. The selenium webdriver extension when upgraded from 2.30 to 2.38 worked fine.